# Get all the tags within an element Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom

Assuming the html below:

```
<div id="contentWrapper">
  <h2>Title<br>Page</h2>
  <div>
  <h4>Subtitle Text<br>
  March 26, 2018</h4>
  <p><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ID" allow="autoplay" allowfullscreen="" width="760" height="428" frameborder="0"></iframe></p>
  </div>
  <p>This is text that adds meaningful value to the website. It is what the user reads</p>
  <p>If you have read up to this part I'm actually impressed.</p>
  <p><strong>* * * * * * *</strong></p>
</div>
```

How can I get every immediate child tag within the contentWrapper as an array that would look like this:

```
[h2, div, p, p, p]
```

Notice I don't want the children of children, just the first child.

I thought about using the querySelectorAll() method, but from what I can tell this requires a css selector as a parameter. I won't know ahead of time what types of tags are in this div so I can't "pre-feed" it selectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  Array.from( document.getElementById("contentWrapper").children, el => el.tagName)
```

[getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

[.children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/children)

[Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
let el = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("#contentWrapper > *")).map(a => a.tagName);
console.log(el);
```

```html
<div id="contentWrapper">
  <h2>Title<br>Page</h2>
  <div>
  <h4>Subtitle Text<br>
  March 26, 2018</h4>
  <p><iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ID" allow="autoplay" allowfullscreen="" width="760" height="428" frameborder="0"></iframe></p>
  </div>
  <p>This is text that adds meaningful value to the website. It is what the user reads</p>
  <p>If you have read up to this part I'm actually impressed.</p>
  <p><strong>* * * * * * *</strong></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a nodelist of the child elements:

```
document.querySelector('#contentWrapper').children;
```

If you want an array of the child element names:

```
[...document.querySelector('#contentWrapper').children].map(el => el.tagName)
```